# Issues installing cocoapods and firebase

Tags: cocoa, cocoapods

When I try to install `cocoapods`, I am stuck at:

```
$ pod install
```

**Error:**

> [!] Invalid `Podfile` file: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input.

The Podfile that is causing the problem:

```
target 'DontForget' do
    # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
    use_frameworks!

    # Pods for DontForget
    pod 'Firebase'
    pod 'FirebaseAuth'
end

target 'Don`tForgetUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
end

end
```

Comment: Can you share your entire Podfile? It sounds like you have an 'end' keyword where it's just expecting the end of the file

Comment: target 'Don`tForget' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!
  # Pods for Don`tForget
pod 'Firebase'
pod 'FirebaseAuth'
  end
  target 'Don`tForgetUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end
end
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
"podfile" 19L, 392C

Answer (score 0):

From your Podfile, I think you have two problems:

1. The apostrophe in `Don'tForgetUITests`.
2. There are two many 'end's at the end of the file. You should delete one of them.